# Getting a variable that can be multiple types in a function in c#

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a function `public static int Name(int num){}`
But I wanna be able to receive more than just an int variable. Not an int and also a string, but either an int or a string (for example). Can I do it without making another function?

Comment: You could take it as a string and then try to parse it into an int; if it fails to parse you know it's not an int...but that's about it. You could also make it generic.

Comment: You can do method overloading. But really for us to give you helpful advice, you should explain the use case. Why do you want to do this? How is it going to be used in your app?

Comment: You'd need two methods as the parameters would need to be handled differently. You might be able to extract some common functionality to a shared method that's called by both.

Comment: Why do you want to do this, rather than having 2 functions, 1 taking an int, and 1 taking a string?   They are completely different types, should probably have different functionality.   Unless it's something that could be handled by generics?

Comment: my vote is for generics if you need one function and not several

Comment: @demonplus Saying "Generics" is not helpful: please explain _specifically_ **how** an approach using C# generics will help, considering that generics cannot really be used to define a closed-set of possible types (i.e. you cannot constraint a type-parameter to be "int or string").

Comment: This isn't really something specific. I just don't like making multiple functions that do the  same thing, sometimes have the exact same code.
I'm just learning c#, I don't know as much as people here haha. Guess it's kind of a dumb question... A lot of you say use generics, I don't really understand how they work, also have just heard of those. I'll try to understand these. Thank you all!

Comment: @DoctorVaitzman Then don't use C#, use Haskell

Answer (score 3):

I'd handle it in two methods of the same name. This is called overloading the method:

```
public static int Name(string num){ return Name(int.Parse(num));}

public static int Name(int num){}
```

This does not have error handling obviously.

I am going to add a little bit more useful example, this allows the user to send either a single email address or a list of them...

```
public static async Task SendMail(string to, string subject, etc)
{
    await SendMail(new List<string> {to}, subject, etc);
}
public static async Task SendMail(List<string> toList, string subject, etc)
{
    //The process of sending a mail
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is quite smart. But someone else suggested "OneOf" so... yeah. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Doctor Vaitzman While a type-union is certainly clever, and can be very useful tool in the toolbox. I would prefer a simple solution like this unless your actual use case can motivate a more complex solution.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use a type-union:

Yes. Use [a *type union*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type), which is a type which represents a value of one specific type from a set of specific types.

C# and .NET doesn't come with built-in support (i.e. first-class union-types), [but the excellent OneOf library works just as well](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf):

So your method would be this:

```cs
public static Int32 Name( OneOf< Int32, String > num ) // rename `num` to something else if it isn't always going to be a number.
{
    if( num.TryPickT0( out Int32 i32Value, out String strValue ) )
    {
        // do stuff with i32Value
    }
    else
    {
        // do stuff with strValue
    }
}
```

Because `OneOf<T0,T1>` has defined implicit conversions from `T0` and `T1` (but no other types) it means you can invoke your `Name` method like so:

```cs
Int32 name0 = Name( 123 ); // `(Int32)123` is implicitly converted to OneOf<Int32,String> by the compiler for you.

Int32 name1 = Name( "abc" ); // `(String)"abc"` is implicitly converted to OneOf<Int32,String> by the compiler for you.

// But you'll get a compile-time error if you use an unsupported type, e.g.:
Int32 name2 = Name( 456.2f ); // `(Single)456.f` cannot be implicitly converted to OneOf<Int32,String>, so you get a compile-time error.
```

---

#### Alternative: abusing `Object` as a poor-man's top-type:

.NET does not have any kind of true [*top-type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type) (that is, a type that can correctly represent a value of *any* type, including `void`, as well as representing value-types without boxing); the closest we have is the `Object` type, which is the supertype of (almost) all reference-types, and also represents boxed value-types.

So if you *want* the set of parameter types to be unbounded *and* if you don't mind boxing, and don't mind losing compile-time safety (and so don't mind runtime exceptions...), then you can do it horribly by using `Object` as a crude top-type:

```cs
public static Int32 Name( Object num ) // rename `num` to something else if it isn't always going to be a number.
{
    if( num is Int32 i32Value )
    {
        // do stuff with i32Value
    }
    else if( num is String strValue )
    {
        // do stuff with strValue
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException( message: "Unsupported argument type.", paramName: nameof(num) );
    }
}
```

...but now it's unsafe because the compiler won't give you an error if you pass in a `Single` (`float`) value unlike with `OneOf<>`:

```cs
Int32 name0 = Name( 123 ); // Int32 boxed and widened to Object.

Int32 name1 = Name( "abc" ); // String widened to Object.

Int32 name2 = Name( 456.2f ); // Single widened to Object. No compile-time error. Instead this will fail at runtime.
```

Comment: Wow this is great! Don't really know what does the if argument means... Thanks tho this is great!

Comment: Right so thanks for explaining further. Unfortunately I don't think there's "OneOf" in c#? But the "object" thing is simple to understand and fulfills my needs so thank you for providing another option :)

Comment: You can get `OneOf` by adding this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OneOf/

Comment: But, what did it gain over a pair of overloaded methods?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [dynamic](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/dynamic-keyword-in-C-Sharp/) keyword

```
public static dynamic foo(int bar) {
    if (bar == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (bar == 2) {
        return "two";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is `dynamic` and improvement over `Object`? Also, the OP is asking about _parameter types_, not return types.

Comment: @Dai you know that with `dynamic` one can write "generic" code for multiple duck-type-identical types... May be even somewhat helpful in `int` and `string` case - i.e. one can use `operator +` (which I think the only useful method common between these two). Granted it is not very C# approach, slow and looses all compile time convenience or static typing... so not a *good* suggestion without all that explanation, but a plausible one (or just trolling one - whichever way one likes to read it :) )

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the function as an int, you can instead specify multiple outputs:

```
static (bool approved, string outname) Name(int num)
{
    if (num == 0)
    {
        return (true, "Poul");
    }
    else if (num == 1)
    {
        return (true, "Hans");
    }
    else
    {
        return (false, "Noname");
    }
}
```

Then you can call the values from the function:

```
var getName = Name(1);

Console.WriteLine(getName.approved);
Console.WriteLine(getName.outname);
```

Comment: Not sure how this solves the problem that two different input types need to be handled?

Comment: Aaaah, i see it now. 
As the description said, he wants to "recieve" multiple types. But by reading some of his comments, i now guess he want to send multiple types to the function instead.